# Javascript code will not run at all

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to sun some javascript on my html page but it doesn't not run at all. I tried to just change the words in a `<p>` tag but nothing happened. I know javascript is enabled on my browser. Here is my code, I can't seem to find anything wrong with it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <h1> Eat Page</h1>
    <p id="test">Hi</p>
    <select id="CusineList"></select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementIdBy("test").innerHTML = "Who";
    </script>

    <p> When </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Note- I am running this file off a folder on my desktop

Comment: JavaScript is often disabled on local files using IE at least. But it can be enabled by allowing active content.

Comment: Although the question does not show any research effort, it still does not worth closing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Who";
```

NOT

```
document.getElementIdBy("test").innerHTML = "Who";
```

Answer (score 3):

Javascript has no function `getElementIdBy`, you have spelled it wrong. You should use  `document.getElementById`.

**Wrong sytnax**

```
  document.getElementIdBy("test").innerHTML = "Who";
```

**Correct syntax**

```
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Who";
```

**You script block should be**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Who";
</script>
```

**Note:** As you are concerned about that you are running file from desktop its absolutely correct in your case.

On more advice put the script block just before the closing tag of body instead of putting it between the HTML. It makes the code bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

this is the right code,

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Who";
```

you made a mistake by typing :

```
document.getElementIdBy("test").innerHTML = "Who";
```

check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3eMV/

Answer (score 0):

Uh, it should be `getElementById`, not `getElementIdBy`. Next time, check out [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) before asking.

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Who";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take care about the document load because you are directly loading the javascript  without any event. If you load the script first and div  later you will surely face problem even if you do make any syntax error.

It should be load after all the document have been loaded.

If you are using jQuery, you can run the script within the `$.ready()` function.